# Athena Query bucket location

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have setup crawler table for CUR reports. Now while setting up Athena table for querying, it is asking for S3 location to store query results. Can I give same location as S3 bucket that has been created to store parquet CUR files?

Please suggest.

Comment: You will at least want to give it a different prefix (subfolder) to store the queries in. But yes, you could use the same bucket if you want.

Comment: Thanks, yes will store the results in a different subfolder